# each character in a string exists in any order in another string

Tags: lua

I have a table of strings:

```
self.rooms = { "n", "s", "e", "w", "nw", "ns", "ne", "sw", "se", "ew", "nsw", "nse", "swe", "nwe", "nsew" }
```

I then get a string that will have any combination of these and I want to find in the above table that contains the letters in any order.

So if I have a string "es" then I should get returned:

"se", "nse", "nsew", "swe" because they all have the letter 'e' AND 's' in them.

Is there any match that can do this?

Comment: and don't returned "swe"? I clarify ..

Comment: @MikeV. You are correct it should return "swe" I just missed that comination. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find a solution for any combination of letters, subject to the mandatory presence of each in the sample:

```
local rooms = { "n", "s", "e", "w", "nw", "ns", "ne", "sw", "se", "ew", "nsw", "nse", "swe", "nwe", "nsew" }

function MyFind (inp, str)
      if str=="" then return false end
      local found=true
      string.gsub(str, '.', function (c)  -- this code can be replaced with a 'for' loop
            if inp:find(c) and found then found=true else  found=false end
          end)
      return found ,inp  
 end

local chars = "se"    -- 1,2,3.. or more letters
for _,v in pairs(rooms) do
      a,b = MyFind (v, chars)
      if a then print (b) end
end
```

print:

```
se
nse
swe
nsew
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rooms = { "n", "s", "e", "w", "nw", "ns", "ne", "sw", "se", "ew", "nsw", "nse", "swe", "nwe", "nsew" }

function normalize(s)
    local t=""
    if s:match("n") then t=t.."n"..".*" end
    if s:match("s") then t=t.."s"..".*" end
    if s:match("e") then t=t.."e"..".*" end
    if s:match("w") then t=t.."w" end
    return t
end

p = normalize("es")

for i,v in ipairs(rooms) do
    if v:match(p) then print(v) end
end
```